# Instrument error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: ios, command-line, instruments, xcodebuild

i try to build my app with the xcodebuild command but i got an error. Here is my command:

```
xcodebuild clean build -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP-SCHEME CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/PATH
```

Here the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
__TMaCSo6Flurry in LoginViewController.o
__TMaCSo6Flurry in RecipientViewController.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Has someone any ideas?
Thank

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong binary of Flurry. They bundle several .a with or without some of the architectures.

You can run **lipo -info** on a library to get which architectures are in the binay.